# Copy value of html element in django (forms) template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

django form with ChoiceField (1,2,3)--> {{Choices.sollicitanten}}
django form with ChoiceField (1,2,3) -->{{ form.vacature_contract }}
the choice options of both fields are the same 1,2,3
What i want is when i select for example, choice 1 in choices.sollicitanten it wil copy this choice to field {{form.vacature_contract}} so that the choice is this field is also 1.

```
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{ Choices.sollicitanten}}</td>.
```

//and i have

```
  <td name="vacature_doel" class="tg-0lax">{{ form.vacature_contract }}</td>
```

//and in html

```
  function FillForm(f) {
  {
   f.vacature_doel.value = f.vacature_bron.value;
   f.sollicitanten_doel.value = f.sollicitanten_bron.value;


  }
}
 </script>
```

//when i hit the submit button the function is run (onclick=FillForm).

//the code above does not seem to do much..what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick both dropdowns by their ids and then add an eventlistener to `sollicitanten` dropdown which will set value of `vacature_contract` dropdown on change or vice versa.

to get the id of your dropdown you can either inspect element or django can guess as django simply assigns id as `id_<your_field_name>`.

Here is the js which should work fine for your code

```
<script>
        let myDropdown = document.getElementById('id_sollicitanten');
        myDropdown.onchange = () => document.getElementById('id_vacature_contract').value = myDropdown.value;
</script>
```

Here, i have added an event listener which will update the vacature_contract dropdown value when the value of sollicitanten is changed.

Comment: @Sander don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your issue.